# Loading images from dropbox to my Imageview

Tags: android

I am trying to load images from dropbox into my Imageview.
I am getting path to  the image as

```
storage/sdcard0/android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch/camera%20uploads/2012-11-13%2020.22.13.jpg
```

However when i connect a FileInputStream to this path ,it give FileNotFoundException .If i directly use

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);
```

No image is shown.

I am not able to create a bitmap from it to show in my imageview.kindly update how to read this image to my Imageview
thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to write the Uri like this:

"file:// + (your path here)"

and you can use Picasso to load images with ease..

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

like this:

```
Picasso.with(yourcontext)
 .load("file:// + (your path here)")
 .resize(50, 50)
 .centerCrop()
 .into(imageView)
```

Comment: if you try without the "file://" but still using picasso, what happens?